# PHP inside HTML form

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP, I just installed XAMPP, and I have a .php file with some variables declared at the start and then the HTML code.Inside the HTML, inside a form, I'm trying to get the value of the variables:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $qty1; ?>" name="qty[]"/>
```

But when I open it in the browser I get the whole php script displayed as a string instead of the value of $qty1.

Comment: Sounds like your webserver isn't actually processing the file with PHP.

Comment: Can you create a PHP file that contains just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and run it in the browser?

Comment: PHP is not working/installed properly, please try uninstalling and re-installing of XAMPP

Comment: Are you accessing the php file directly or are you accessing it via localhost? Does the url start with `file:///` ?

Comment: Are you using webhost, if yes, which one? Some hosts do only support HTML or need you to choose which features you want to enable. Also make sure that the file is indeed saved as a .php file and not just with the name "x.php".html

Comment: try to check the following:
- Did you name the file with .php extension instead of .html ?
- Did you open the file in the browser by accessing localhost/yourFileName.php ?

Comment: the <?php phpinfo(); ?> file is just blank in the browser

Comment: the file is on localhost path is: file:///D:/XAMPP/htdocs/cart.php

Comment: Try entering `http://localhost/cart.php` in your address bar.

Comment: Ahh, sorry guys, I figured it out, I was opening the file by double clicking it inside my D partition and the path was file:///D:/XAMPP/htdocscart.php instead of localhost/cart.php. Stupid mistake...it works just fine.

Thanks for all the answers :)

Comment: Can't answer my own question before 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you saved your file as .html instead of .php. Try to check that.

If you saved it as php, remember that you have to access with `http://localhost/PATH-TO-PHP-FILE.php` or `http://127.0.0.1/PATH-TO-PHP-FILE.php`. When you access in this way (localhost), the php file will be processed and then the variable will appear correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the php file inside the server's root directory and access via

```
localhost/filename.php
```

to run the php code.

For xampp the root directory is `C:/xampp/htdocs/`
(for windows)